# Regarding combining queries into one

Tags: sql

I have query that is and I have executed the query..

first is the TXN_HEADER table .

```
select * from TXN_HEADER where txhd_receipt_id = 'receipt_id_val' and till_short_desc = 'till_no_val'
```

from the above TXN_HEADER table we get the transaction_no value ( e.g. txhd_txn_nr) which is used to find the transactional details in TXN_DETAIL table.

```
select * from TXN_DETAIL where txhd_txn_nr = 'transaction_no_val' and till_short_desc = 'till_no_val
```

My query is that I am writing these queries seprately can you guys please advise by which I can combine them into single query by any means , I means through subquery , through joins . please advise.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the tables in the `FROM` clause.  Can you state which fields in `TXN_HEADER` relate to which fields in `TXN_DETAIL`?  Is there some identity field in one referenced by the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join version:

```
select * 
  from TXN_HEADER 
 inner join TXN_DETAIL 
    on TXN_HEADER.txhd_txn_nr = TXN_DETAIL.txhd_txn_nr
 where TXN_HEADER.txhd_receipt_id = 'receipt_id_val' 
   and TXN_HEADER.till_short_desc = 'till_no_val'
   and TXN_DETAIL.till_short_desc = 'till_no_val'
```

Answer (score 0):

If column [txhd_txn_nr] can related these two tables,you can try using this query:

```
select * from TXN_DETAIL where txhd_txn_nr in (select transaction_no_val from TXN_HEADER where txhd_receipt_id = 'receipt_id_val' and till_short_desc = 'till_no_val') and till_short_desc = 'till_no_val
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have an id to join

```
select * from TXN_HEADER H
join TXN_DETAIL D
on H.<id>=D.<id>
where  H.txhd_receipt_id = 'receipt_id_val' and H.till_short_desc = 'till_no_val'
and D.txhd_txn_nr = 'transaction_no_val' and D.till_short_desc = 'till_no_val'
```